# Mat table scrollbar

Tags: css, mat-table

I want to add a horizontal scrollbar for my mat-table, if the columns are overlapping each other.

My html:

```
<div class="table-container">
  <mat-table>.....</mat-table>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;

  mat-table {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

If I change the width of my mat-table to e.g. 2500px, it will behave correctly, but I don't want to specify it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to specify it, how else should the browser decide on its own, how much space to consume?

Comment: Yea, I realized... I just added different sizes on breakpoints.. better than nothing.